# Table structure of multilevel category

Tags: codeigniter

I am required a Table structure for the following category and sub categories :

main category   1st child    2nd child   3rd child
Electronics   =>  Computer =>  Laptop  => Dell
what will be the perfect table for the category and subcategories ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it

```
id      |   name        |   parent_id
---------------------------------------
1       |   Electronics |   0
2       |   Computer    |   1
3       |   Laptop      |   1
4       |   Dell        |   1
5       |   Dual Core I |   3
```

0 means it is a parent category. Computer contains 1 as parent category which means it is child of Electronics. Dual Core I contains 3 means it is child of Laptop. This way you can have as many levels as you want.

Comment: Shouldn't the laptop parent_id be 2, and Dell 3. You also have two rows with the same `id`.

Comment: Well thanks and this is some sample data i wanted to present. I presented Laptop as child of electronics as he has mentioned in question. 3 children for Electronics