# Appropriate table structure of multileval category and subcategoies

Tags: codeigniter-2

I want to create a table structure of the following requirement :

I have some main categories(e.g Electronics, Dress etc.). I want to add subcategories under these categories upto three level.

**Suppose main category is Electronics. It's child category is computer. Computer's child category is Laptop and Laptop's child category is Dell.
( Electronics => computer => Laptop => Dell )**

Like the above example there are many categories and sub categories.
So, what is the appropriate table structure of it?

Comment: Fully Normalized is always best at design time (and, arguably, the rest of the time also).

Comment: @PrasenjitHazra did you really see the answer i posted for you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151856/table-structure-of-multilevel-category/15151897#15151897)?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to create one table with column parent_id.

For example:

TABLE category

category_id, 
category_name
category_parent_id

parent_id will contain the id of parent_id.

For ex.

```
category_id | category_name | category_parent_id

    1       | Electronics   | 0
    2       | Dress         | 0
    3       | Computer      | 1
    4       | T-shirt       | 2
    5       | Llaptop       | 3
    6       | Dell          | 5
```